# route -n gives output "route: fscanf"

Tags: bash, shell, networking, route

If I boot my system and no interface has an IP address I get the above output. However if I give an interface an IP, even if I remove it again, this will disappear. Why does this happen?

Is it that there is some file created that route tries to read?

Comment: You can probably figure out why by doing this: `strace -s 2000 -o my.log route -n`.

Comment: @slm Thanks, i tried this, but it didn't give me anything useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`route` reads `/proc/net/route` & `route: fscanf` appears on `stderr`.

Stream information from a configured interface:

```
# cat /proc/net/route
Iface   Destination Gateway     Flags   RefCnt  Use Metric  Mask        MTU Window  IRTT                                                       
eth0    00000000    02F7A8C0    0003    0   0   202 00000000    0   0   0                                                                             
eth0    00F7A8C0    00000000    0001    0   0   0   00FFFFFF    0   0   0
```

The [fscanf c++ function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) appears as an **error** from `route` because `/proc/net/route` is empty.

If you deconfigure the interface & bring it down again there is some initial information but no stream information:

```
# cat /proc/net/route
Iface   Destination Gateway     Flags   RefCnt  Use Metric  Mask        MTU Window  IRTT
```

I [test for this **error** in a script](https://github.com/itoffshore/alpine-linux-scripts/commit/2916c9cf3c51fd2a92257598b55a3e1f75e4e128) to check if interfaces should be configured.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect, my bad for figuring this out and forgetting to update this.